# How to simplify Access Queries

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm building a query that will add a column for edited names and edited id numbers. I currently have 10 queries that edits and adds the columns that are combined with a macro. How can simplify this query into one?

I have an excel spreadsheet with the columns: 
Name 1, New Name 1, Name 2, New Name 2, ID 1, New ID 1, ID 2, New ID 2, ID 3, New ID 3.

I fill in the columns Name 1, Name 2, ID 1, ID 2, ID3 and load this sheet on to an access table called Scrub.

I also have a spreadsheet called NameEdit which I will refer to later.

I run the macro and a new excel sheet is exported with additional columns:
New Name 1, New Name 2, New ID 1, New ID 2, New ID3 3

I currently have 10 queries that are combined with a macro

1. In a New Column: "New ID 1" Format ID 1 to add leading zeros to make the length at least 7
2. Delete any New ID 1 if the length of ID 1 is less than 7.
3. In a New Column: "New ID 2" Format ID 1 to add leading zeros to make the length at least 7
4. Delete any New ID 2 if the length of ID 2 is less than 7.
5. In a New Column New ID 3 Format ID 3 to show only numbers. (remove special characters and letters)
6. Delete New ID 3 if the corresponding ID 3 is less than 7.
7. In a New Column, New Name 1 format Name 1 (INNERJOIN with another table)
8. In a New Column, New Name 2, format Name 2 (INNERJOIN with another table)
9. Delete rows if New ID 1, New ID 2, and New ID 3 are all blank
10. Export with formatting

I have a lot of code for the 10 queries, here are some. Some of the codes are similar with one another.

Add Column: New ID 1

```
    UPDATE Scrub SET NewID1 = format(REPLACE([ID1],"-",""),"0000000");
```

Delete New ID 1 if ID1's length is less than 7.

```
    UPDATE SCRUB SET NEWID1 = "" WHERE LEN(ID1)<7;
```

Add Column: New ID 3

```
    UPDATE SCRUB SET NEWID3 = "" ID3 Like '*[a-z]*';
```

Add Column: New Name 1

```
    UPDATE Scrub INNER JOIN NameEdit ON SCRUB.[Name1] = NameEdit.[Name] SET SCRUB.NewName1 = NameEdit.[Format];
```

DELETE

```
    DELETE * FROM SCRUB WHERE LEN(NEWID1)=0 AND LEN(NEWID2)=0 AND LEN(NEWID3)=0;
```

I expect the output to be an excel spreadsheet with the New Columns filled in.
The problem I'm having is that the NEWID3 doesn't edit to remove the special characters.
Also when the IDs are deleted, it still shows as a blank space in excel.
In the end, I would like to combine all of these in to one query.

Comment: There is no WHERE keyword in ID3 update action.

Comment: Is there a pressing need to use the database? It should be fairly straight forward to do the scrubbing in Excel. Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: I have done some stuff where I used several queries to calculate specific numbers in an Access Application. It is one of the hardest to maintain and understand part of the program. All the data is in Access. IMHO Excel is very good for scrubbing data. Frequently, I can get the data scrubbed without writing vba code.

Comment: @PerrySugerman I use the database because that's where I have my edited names saved and that's a HUGE file. The edited name removes suffixes but keeps the prefix, uses the name in parentheses if any, uses the name after the hyphen if the name is hyphenated. I used to use excel before, by using =text(A1,"0000000") to add leading zeros to the ID, but I couldn't figure out how to remove special characters and alphabets, and edit the names without having to do a VLOOKUP from a huge file.

Comment: The expression * [a-z] * matches a lot of strings. What sort of string are in your data that you think will not be matched. I tried this in the small and it matched all my choices. I had to put paces in the expression because otherwise they were edited out.